# Custom DataGridview Width when calling a MySql Table

Tags: c#, mysql, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn

I'm Trying to make a program that lists name of all the sub folders of a chosen folder, it all work but i cant seem to make a custom width for my datagridview , I've been looking for an answer for hours , but they mostly wont work, I tried :

Gata.columns[0].width = 100;
or stuff like this , but they don't work.

this did not work either : [MSDN - DataGridViewColumn.Width Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.width(v=vs.110).aspx)

it seems that they are mainly used for unbound grids , that i have no idea about I tried to link my MySql table to one but failed again. It is pretty much the 2nd program i'm writing so please forgive my noobishness !

I want my table to look like the [picture here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X1ZUS.png)

the auto-size and fill statement on grids properties wont do the trick.
I've checked a lot of answer on stack-overflow but none answers this. Thanks in advance for the help !

here is the code im using :

```
            try
            {
                String sqlcon = "datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=anime;password=anime";
                MySqlConnection myanimedb0con = new MySqlConnection(sqlcon);
                MySqlDataAdapter myanimedb0ada = new MySqlDataAdapter();
                MySqlCommand myanimedb0cmd = new MySqlCommand("insert into anime.anime0list ( Anime_Name , Anime_Root ) values ( '" + MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlHelper.EscapeString(dir.Name) + "' , '" + dir.Parent + "' );", myanimedb0con);
                MySqlCommandBuilder myanimedb0cb = new MySqlCommandBuilder(myanimedb0ada);
                myanimedb0ada.SelectCommand = myanimedb0cmd;
                DataTable Gate = new DataTable();
                myanimedb0ada.Fill(Gate);
                BindingSource b0Gate = new BindingSource();
                b0Gate.DataSource = Gate;
                this.Gate.DataSource = b0Gate;
                myanimedb0ada.Update(Gate);

                // Updating the table after adding an item

                MySqlCommand myanimedb0cmd2 = new MySqlCommand("select * from anime.anime0list ;", myanimedb0con);

                myanimedb0ada.SelectCommand = myanimedb0cmd2;

                myanimedb0ada.Fill(Gate);
                b0Gate.DataSource = Gate;
                this.Gate.DataSource = b0Gate;
                myanimedb0ada.Update(Gate);
```

Comment: Please add your code and the error you get if any.

Comment: I'm not getting any errors right now, and the code above is what im using right now to call the table from mysql database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it is to set the column width one at a time like this if you are using the default windows forms or web controls:

```
private void Button5_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    DataGridViewColumn column = dataGridView.Columns[0];
    column.Width = 60;
}
```

You can also do it by column like this if you like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < DataGridView1.Columns.Count; i++)
{
    DataGridView1.Columns[i].Width = 30;
}
```

Or you can manipulate it within the event...

```
dataGridView1.ColumnAdded += new DataGridViewColumnEventHandler(dataGridView1_ColumnAdded);   
void dataGridView1_ColumnAdded(object sender, DataGridViewColumnEventArgs e)   
{   
    e.Column.Width = 30;   
}
```

This has to work, gauranteed. Please let me know if you come right?

Comment: Ah , I used the 2nd code and it works just fine , thank you a lot , for some strange reason the first code doesn't work , i had tried it before (MSDN). my reputation wont let me to up-vote your answer sadly ! one last question , can if give it a % ? like the first column takes 10% of the total width of the table ?

Comment: Try something like this: TableRow.Width = new Unit("25%")

Comment: sadly the last code did not work but I wrote this one which works without problem : int i = DataGridView.Width;   FirstC = (i*20)/100;  DataGridView1.Columns[0].Width = FirstC;                      once again thanks for taking time and answering my question.

Comment: Only a pleasure, I'm glad I could help. Thanks for the feedback also ;)

Answer (score 0):

If your `DataGridView` is anchored left and right, as it seems to be in your screenshot, you should consider using the `[DataGridViewColumn.FillWeight][1]` property. This property allows you to give a weight to each column so that you can tell which one has to be the largest one.

You should also look at the `[DataGridViewColumn.AutoSizeMode][2]` property.

In your example, I would set `AutoSizeMode` to `AllCells` for *ID* and *Anime_root* columns , and `AutoSizeMode` to `Fill` for *Anime_name* column.

Finally, you can look at `[DataGridView.MinimumWidth][3]` property to define the minimum width of your columns.